# VBA refer to PivotTable column by its SourceName

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

How to select PivotTable column by its `.SourceName`? Or how to get the SourceName of PivotTable column based on ActiveCell.Column? I need something like:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).SourceName("MyColumn").Select
```

The reason why I need it is because the pf.Caption changes dynamically (i.e. due to Country settings), while the `.SourceName` is always the same.

Comment: Something like `pt.PivotFields("Years").PivotItems("2004").DataRange.Select`.  Jon Peltier has a great page on referencing different parts of a pivot table. http://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: Add with VBA PivotField to a table with default SUM. Then its name (Caption) is `Sum of MyColumn` if you have English Excel. Another user of the same macro who has say Transilvania language or (whatever other) will have `Asdf of MyColumn`. Jon's code requires using Caption name `pt.PivotFields("Years").PivotItems("Sum of 2004").DataRange.Select`. It works on Caption name, not on SourceName.

Comment: Maybe based on the ActiveCell - `pt.PivotFields(ActiveCell.PivotItem.Caption).DataRange.Select`.  If you add a Watch on a cell within the pivot table (or ActiveCell) and have a look down the list to PivotCell, PivotField, PivotItem and PivotTable you should be able to get it to do what you want.

Comment: What about if I know the SourceName, and I do not know the Caption name. Is there a way to refer to column?

Answer (score 0):

Think I'm getting myself confused now, but wanted to post the code 'cos it might help.

So if you select your source data it will find the pivot table created off it, it will list the pivotfields in that table and you can get to the pivotitems in the pivotfields, etc.

Any help?

```
Sub FindPivots()

    Dim MyData As Range
    Dim MySourceData As String
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pvtfld As PivotField
    Dim pvtitm As PivotItem

    Set MyData = Selection
    MySourceData = IIf(InStr(MyData.Parent.Name, " ") > 0, _
        "'" & MyData.Parent.Name & "'!", _
        MyData.Parent.Name & "!") & MyData.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In wrkSht.PivotTables
            If pt.SourceData = MySourceData Then
                For Each pvtfld In pt.PivotFields
                    Debug.Print pvtfld.SourceName & " : "
                    'For Each pvtitm In pvtfld.PivotItems
                        Debug.Print pvtfld.SourceName
                    'Next pvtitm
                Next pvtfld
            End If
        Next pt
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```